# Everything breaks after using PlayOneShot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a game I am working on, the player uses a cube to open doors. When the player interacts with the cube while near the door, the door slides open. I am now trying to make it so that while it slides open, it makes a sound as doors should but I kinda ran into some issues. When I tried to add in the sound for the door, it ignored the part where the door should open altogether.

Here is what I did:

I added an AudioSource to the Cube's child object, CORE because the Cube object already contains an AudioSource which will play at the same time as this sound and assigned it in my Cube's script...

`public AudioSource Woosh;`

```
 void Start()
{
    //Debug.Log("Script initialized!");
    Hm = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    anim = GameObject.Find("TheFirstDoor").GetComponent<Animator>();
    //Door = GameObject.Find("TheFirstDoor").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    Woosh = GameObject.Find("CORE").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
```

Here's the interactive part of the script, it runs a check but for some reason, it is pretending `CanBeKey` is false...

```
    public void OnActivate()
{
    if(HasPlayed == false) //Have I played? Has the Time out passed?
    {
        HasPlayedFirstTime = true;
        Hm.Play();
        HasPlayed = true;
        PlayTimeOut = 30.0f;
        if(CanBeKey == true)
        {
            anim.Play("Door_Open");
            //Door.Play();
            StartCoroutine(PlayDaWoosh());
            Debug.Log("OPENING!");
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is the IEnumerator part of the script, `PlayDaWoosh()`

```
    IEnumerator PlayDaWoosh()
{
    Woosh.PlayOneShot(Woosh.clip);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Woosh.clip.length);
}
```

I am aware that the last code snippet is a bit messy but it was the best thing I can think of.

Here is the full script in case you are that curious.....

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CUBE_CORE : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource Hm; // HM!!!
    private bool HasPlayed = false;
    public float PlayTimeOut = 0.0f;
    public static bool CanBeKey = false;
    public Animator anim;
    public static bool HasPlayedFirstTime = false;
    public static AudioSource Door;
    public AudioSource Woosh;

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Debug.Log("Script initialized!");
    Hm = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    anim = GameObject.Find("TheFirstDoor").GetComponent<Animator>();
    //Door = GameObject.Find("TheFirstDoor").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    Woosh = GameObject.Find("CORE").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(HasPlayed == true)
    {
        if (PlayTimeOut < 0.0f)
        {
            HasPlayed = false;
        }
        PlayTimeOut -= Time.smoothDeltaTime;
    }
}
public void OnActivate()
{
    if(HasPlayed == false) //Have I played? Has the Time out passed?
    {
        HasPlayedFirstTime = true;
        Hm.Play();
        HasPlayed = true;
        PlayTimeOut = 30.0f;
        if(CanBeKey == true)
        {
            anim.Play("Door_Open");
            //Door.Play();
            StartCoroutine(PlayDaWoosh());
            Debug.Log("OPENING!");
        }
    }
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.name == "SecondDoor")
    {
        anim = GameObject.Find("DoorSecond").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    if(other.gameObject.name == "ThirdDoor")
    {
        anim = GameObject.Find("TheThirdDoor").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    if(other.gameObject.name == "FourthDoor")
    {
        anim = GameObject.Find("TheFourthDoor").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
}
IEnumerator PlayDaWoosh()
{
    Woosh.PlayOneShot(Woosh.clip);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Woosh.clip.length);
}
```

}

Expected result: Door opening and sound playing

Actual result: Neither happening unless I remove anything that has to do with the `Woosh`

I apologize ahead of time if I wasn't specific enough or if the question was answered somewhere else. I am relatively new here.

Comment: Looks like it's to do with the way that coroutines work with frames. Try reading this and see if it helps you figure out your issue: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: Where method OnActivate() is invoked?

Comment: @Wolfik OnActivate() happens when the player interacts with the cube when the player walks up to it, a text will pop up instructing the player to press 'E' to interact. The cube has a component that will invoke that part of the script when the player enters a box collider and presses the button.

Comment: @RossGurbutt Thank you for the link, I learned a lot more about coroutines and discovered the `StopCoroutine()` Function. If I could, I would mark your reply as the answer for you have enabled me to fix the problem. Under `StartCoroutine(PlayDaWooosh());` I inserted a `StopCoroutine(PlayDaWoosh());` and then in the enumerator itself, I deleted the yield return new and placed a `yield return null` to instruct the coroutine to stop what it is doing. Again, thanks a lot for the help, the door works as intended now.